# Git showing lots of changes and untracked files after checkout

Tags: git

So I'm on a branch, let's call it `feature/PRO-10` and I want to switch to another branch to quickly check the state of a piece of code. I do a `git stash` to stash my changes and then a `git checkout bugfix/PRO-13` to go to the branch I want to look at code on. I finish what I want to do on this branch (without making any changes) and do a `git checkout feature/PRO-10` to get back to the branch I was developing on. I'm about to do a `git stash pop` but wait! There's a behemoth of modified and untracked files along with other changes.

How did they turn up? I never did any sort of merge. I may have done a `git pull` to get up-to-date with `bugfix/PRO-13` but I don't see why that would make loads of changes that follow me to my original branch.

The worst thing is sometimes I'll do a `git stash pop` before doing a `git status`, meaning I'll probably have my original changes mixed in with all this other gumph that seemingly came out of nowhere.

Where are these changes coming from and are they safe to get rid of?

Comment: after `git stash`, what does `git status` show?

Comment: It shows `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`. The changes that have magically popped up are changes completely unrelated to anything I've stashed.

Comment: What are the modified and untracked files you see after switching to your original branch? Could they have been modified anytime earlier? Did you by any chance `apply` or `pop` your stash while you were on the other branch `bugfix/PRO-13`?

Comment: They *seem* to be changes related to the branch that I switched to (in this scenario `bugfix/PRO-13`). It's like I switched to that branch, pulled all these changes, switched back to my development branch and the changes I'd pulled came with me.

Comment: When you say "switched back to my development branch and the changes I'd pulled came with me" do you mean the merged changes or the untracked and modified files you mention in your question?

Comment: They seem to be the changes between my development branch (`feature/PRO-10`) and the branch I looked at code on (`bugfix/PRO-13`). These branches aren't up-to-date with each other and when I switched back to `feature/PRO-10` it seemed to bring with me all changes between `feature/PRO-10` and `bugfix/PRO-13`. Sorry, I know I'm not explaining this well :/

Comment: Do you see any files under `both modified` when you type `git status` ?

Comment: Nope, nothing under `both modified`. Just changes staged for commit, unstaged changes and untracked files.

Comment: The only thing then, I can think of is that you applied your stash somewhere in the process or did not stash all your changes before switching branches. Not perfectly sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `git checkout`, git tries to delete the things that don't exist in the destination branch.  If you've got a virus scanner running, it'll leave them behind or prompt you.  If you're confident you have everything either stashed or committed, you can `git reset --hard` to get rid of these abandoned files.  Be careful though as this specifically says "revert all local changes without warning" so make sure that's really what you wanted to do.